# Allow devise login with alias_attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, warden

I am trying to build an API that deals with an existing mobile app. The mobile App uses username but it is really just an email and instead of reworking devise to have a confusing system of username which really is email. I wanted to use `alias_attribute`. It seems to work for everything but the login. 
The JSON comes up as

`{ "username":"test12345@gmail.com", "password":"password" }`

and I permit the keys
`devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:username, :password])`
but it fails at 
`self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)`
It seems like warden is ignoring the alias_attribute. If I change the username to email it works fine. I have tried overwriting the database auth function on the model but it never gets to that line.

Comment: Have you tried setting `config.authentication_keys = [ :email, :username ]` in `config/initializers/devise.rb`? `alias_attribute` is kind of irrelevant here - you need to configure warden to use the correct key from the params as the primary identifier.

Answer (score 0):

from what I can tell, it's way easier to override the default sessions_controller behaviour

inside you sessions controller:

```
def create
  if params[:user][:username]
    params[:user][:email] = params[:user][:username]
  end
  super
end
```

or if yo don't want to overrride the `create` method then add

```
before_action :override_params, only: :create

def override_params
  if params[:user][:username]
    params[:user][:email] = params[:user][:username]
  end
end
```

it's not nice, but should do the trick. And if you don't have to rewrite the insides of devise then I'd give it a go.

Otherwise you would have to do

1. add new authentication key to devise initializer
   (inside `config/initializers/devise.rb` add `config.authentication_keys = [:email, :username]`)
2. then you would have to override `find_for_database_authnetication` in `User` model to search the user by the username param value (check https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb#L231). Because `alias_attribute` doesn't really help you in this scenario
3. probably some other steps as well

All in all, the dirty method seems simpler and more straightforward

EDIT:

also, checkout this page https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign_in-using-their-username-or-email-address

maybe it will be of some help